# Building Xcode project without a provisioning profile

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I'm sorry if it's already answered here but I wasn't able to find it.

I want to play a bit with [DriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit) and [SEXTs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity) but I'm not in the Apple Developer Program. Is there a way to build a project using DriverKit in Xcode without using a provisioning profile? Or can I generate a 'fake' one manually? I'm trying to build a DriverKit [project](https://github.com/knightsc/USBApp) by Scott Knight but I'm getting "*"USBApp" requires a provisioning profile with the System Extension feature.*" and "*"MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver" requires a provisioning profile.*" errors.

I tried to run a [small demo](https://github.com/shinvou/EndpointSecurityTest/tree/master/EndpointSecurityTest) which uses the Endpoint Security framework. I built it using clang and ran it in a virtual machine with SIP disabled. However, I'd like to try to develop a bigger project (and to also try writing DEXT) and I don't want to build it using clang every time neither to use Xcode in the virtual machine (I don't even know if I would be able to build it using Xcode in the VM plus disk space limitations).

My goal is to develop and build in the comfort of my host machine without need of the VM, and then to run (and debug) it in the virtual machine.

P.S.: For ones that want to build the same demo (got SIGSEGV but I was able to build it and run it on Catalina 10.15.3):

```
clang -framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration /usr/lib/libEndpointSecurity.dylib /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib EndpointSecurityDemo.m -o esdemo
```

Comment: Ok, so I know I'm not able to do projects that need a provisioning profile (i.e. an endpoint security project) fully in Xcode even in the VM with SIP disabled. The only way to run the project is to delete entitlement file path from build settings of Xcode, build it and then I need to sign it manually using codesign, ad-hoc certificate and manually created entitlements file.

Comment: Any solution to this? I want to build one endpoint security app with the extension but as I don't have a developer account I can't